# Accessing files in folders by defining multiple variables in bash script

Tags: bash, for-loop, variables

I am trying to access files in many folders to copy them into a new folder.

I define the folders using variables as below.

```
q="Q1-students-answer2"  # this is a folder

achari1="AHMAD_JAUHARI_BIN_NAZAIDI_._1587851_assignsubmission_file_"   #this is folder
achari2="AINUL_SUHAILAH_BINTI_MAIL_._1587856_assignsubmission_file_"   #this is folder
achari3="AMIRAH_NURAZIZAH_._1587875_assignsubmission_file_"   #this is folder
achari4="AMIRAH_RADHIANIE_BINTI_RINING_._1587865_assignsubmission_file_"   #this is folder
```

Below is the "for" block to recursively access the folders that I defined using variables as achari1, achari2, achari3, and achari4

```
for i in {1..4};do
    
    echo $q/$achari$i   

done
```

This code gives the output as

```
Q1-students-answer2/1
Q1-students-answer2/2
Q1-students-answer2/3
Q1-students-answer2/4
```

Instead I want the output as

```
Q1-students-answer2/AHMAD_JAUHARI_BIN_NAZAIDI_._1587851_assignsubmission_file_
Q1-students-answer2/AINUL_SUHAILAH_BINTI_MAIL_._1587856_assignsubmission_file_
Q1-students-answer2/AMIRAH_NURAZIZAH_._1587875_assignsubmission_file_
Q1-students-answer2/AMIRAH_RADHIANIE_BINTI_RINING_._1587865_assignsubmission_file_
```

I have tried many other ways like

```
echo "$q/achari$i"

or 

(cd $q/achari$i;
echo  $q/$(achari)$i;
cd ../)

or 

echo "$q/$(achari)$i"
```

but all these above seems not working.

Appreciate if someone could show what is the wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use an array, not separate variables:

```
achari=("AHMAD_JAUHARI_BIN_NAZAIDI_._1587851_assignsubmission_file_"   #this is folder
        "AINUL_SUHAILAH_BINTI_MAIL_._1587856_assignsubmission_file_"   #this is folder
        "AMIRAH_NURAZIZAH_._1587875_assignsubmission_file_"   #this is folder
        "AMIRAH_RADHIANIE_BINTI_RINING_._1587865_assignsubmission_file_")   #this is folder
for dir in "${achari[@]}"; do
    echo $q/$dir
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Either use an array, or use indirect expansion as in:

```
#!/bin/bash

q="Q1-students-answer2"  # this is a folder

achari1="AHMAD_JAUHARI_BIN_NAZAIDI_._1587851_assignsubmission_file_"
achari2="AINUL_SUHAILAH_BINTI_MAIL_._1587856_assignsubmission_file_"
achari3="AMIRAH_NURAZIZAH_._1587875_assignsubmission_file_"
achari4="AMIRAH_RADHIANIE_BINTI_RINING_._1587865_assignsubmission_file_"

for i in {1..4}; do
    t=achari$i
    echo "$q"/"${!t}"
done
```